# TypeError: Cannot create property '_fullPath' on string ''

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This mongoose error was shown when populating collections.

```
Model.find().populate('someCollection')
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you are trying to do and the error you are getting?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please show the error. You have just written a mongo query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error was generated with the version `6.1.3` of mongoose .
To prevent this horrible fault from mongoose team please downgrade it to `6.1.2`

Comment: It has nothing to do with the versions.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed my problem:

```
Model.find().populate({path: 'someCollection'})
```

Comment: This won't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the reference id that **does NOT exist**, for example:

```
 the whole item:

    {
       "_id": "61e21fb9e07c33f81b4cafc4",
       "orderItems": [
           "61e21fb9e07c33f81b4cafc0", // ref id
           "61e21fb9e07c33f81b4cafc1"  // ref id
       ],
       ...
    }
```

If either of the two ref ids doesn't exist, you'd get the said error:

```
    TypeError: Cannot create property '_fullPath' on string
```

In that case, you need to discard/delete the whole item, and use **the existing ref ids** to create a new item.